# Can someone help me identify where this rock is located in Lanzarote?

Tags: identify-this, landmarks, geography, canary-islands

Several years ago, I drove around Lanzarote, and came across this strange rock, but I cannot remember why.  Can someone identify where it is?

[image: Unknown Rock]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Alamy stock photos](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-lanzarote-lava-landscape-on-the-calle-del-candil-near-el-majon-location-47518579.html?pv=1&stamp=2&imageid=2FF3AEE9-EFE7-4A38-9713-858AE14D0660&p=11365&n=2&orientation=0&pn=1&searchtype=0&IsFromSearch=1&srch=foo%3Dbar%26st%3D0%26sortby%3D2%26qt%3DCalle%2520del%2520Candil%26qt_raw%3DCalle%2520del%2520Candil%26qn%3D%26lic%3D3%26mr%3D0%26pr%3D0%26aoa%3D1%26creative%3D%26videos%3D%26nu%3D%26ccc%3D%26bespoke%3D%26apalib%3D%26ag%3D0%26hc%3D0%26et%3D0x000000000000000000000%26vp%3D0%26loc%3D0%26ot%3D0%26imgt%3D0%26dtfr%3D%26dtto%3D%26size%3D0xFF%26blackwhite%3D%26cutout%3D%26archive%3D1%26name%3D%26groupid%3D%26pseudoid%3D%26userid%3D%26id%3D%26a%3D%26xstx%3D0%26cbstore%3D1%26resultview%3DsortbyPopular%26lightbox%3D%26gname%3D%26gtype%3D%26apalic%3D%26tbar%3D1%26pc%3D%26simid%3D%26cap%3D1%26customgeoip%3D%26vd%3D0%26cid%3D%26pe%3D%26so%3D%26lb%3D%26langcode%3Den%26saveQry%3D%26editorial%3D1%26t%3D0%26edoptin%3D) has an almost identical image, identifying it as the Lanzarote lava landscape on the Calle del Candil, near El Majon. Location for off-road quad biking round tufa rocks.

Answer (score 2):

by some researching I found the location!
Here is the google maps link: [Google Maps](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/29%C2%B003'24.1%22N+13%C2%B030'15.0%22W/@29.0565392,-13.5042288,991m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d29.056707!4d-13.5041644?hl=nl)

The coordinates are:  29°3'24.145124"N, 13°30'14.991932"W

Comment: Worth pointing out there is a streetview looking right at these rocks. The view on the pic in the Q is towards the street. +1